# WCF: How to get Host IP or Server Name

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service that is hosted via IIS on multiple web servers.  I have a logging method that logs the calls to the database and I'd like to log which server the call is executing on.

Does anyone know how to get the host server name or IP address that the WCF call is executing on?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use Dns.GetHostName(), because it's much better to get the name of the computer than the host IP. Consider the case when your host computer have more than one IP address, has virtual network cards (VMWare).

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for us. Make sure you have a reference to System.ServiceModel. Then implement the following code in your service method:

```
var context = System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current;

RemoteEndpointMessageProperty property = (RemoteEndpointMessageProperty)context.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name];

string externalIP = property.Address;
```

Comment: It's client ip address, not host.

Answer (score 1):

Dns.GetHostName() is what i use the most.

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.MachineName
```

does axactly that

Answer (score 0):

DNS host name doesn't work because many servers have multiple host names and you don't know which one the service was called on. IIRC, IIS can call differing web services based on which host name was specified making the matter worse.  using .Current is great if you're not running a single instance, in which case you dont always have a non-null context object, which is my case for all of the above. If anyone has anything more solid, please share :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the current base address of server(host).

```cs
using System.ServiceModel;

var baseAddress = OperationContext.Current.Host.BaseAddresses[0].Authority;
```